# Alternative for \tl_if_blank:e

Tags: expl3

Recently I started to check those code I wrote when I first learned about `expl3`. I found that there are many usage of `\tl_if_blank:e...` for testing if the content of a macro is empty or not. But now I realize that this might be unsafe for general user input (for example, if the user input contains something like `\color{red}`, it would stop working).

I assume that the reason that I chose to use `\tl_if_blank:e...` is probably because `\tl_if_blank:n...` or `\str_if_empty:n...` didn't work as expected. For example, some macros like `\@date` may seem empty if you output it to the pdf, but when you test it with `n`-variant commands it is not reflect as being empty.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\date{}
% \date{\color{red}}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_if_blank:eTF { \@date } {EMPTY} {SOMETHING}
\par
\tl_if_blank:nTF { \@date } {EMPTY} {SOMETHING}
\par
\str_if_empty:nTF { \@date } {EMPTY} {SOMETHING}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Thus I would like to ask that, how should I modify my code in a safe way while still obtaining the correct result?

Comment: I think we need to understand why you are doing this: it seems pretty risky in general. I'd imagine that either `\@date` would be empty (`\tl_if_empty:NTF` true) or otherwise it has 'valid content' that should be typeset, even if the result is empty.

Comment: @JosephWright In this particular case, my package needs to decide an appropriate vertical spacing according to whether `\@date` is empty or not. The "empty" here means that the result is empty (the macro itself is not necessarily empty), and that was probably why I chose to use the `e`-variant (at the time I didn't know that it could cause more severe trouble).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are interested in the *typeset output*, I would test exactly that:

```latex
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \@date }
\dim_compare:nNnTF { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box } > \c_zero_dim
  { FALSE CODE }
  { TRUE CODE }
```

One would make this into a stand-alone test using `\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn`:

```
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npn \jinwin_if_outout_blank:n #1 { T , F, TF }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {#1}
      \dim_compare:nNnTF { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box } > \c_zero_dim
        { \group_end: \prg_return_false: }
        { \group_end: \prg_return_true: }
  }
```

If you want to know if the expansion of user input is blank, if you can be non-expandable use `\protected@edef`

```latex
\protected@edef \@tempa {\@date}
\tl_if_empty:NTF \@tempa
  { TRUE CODE }
  { FALSE CODE }
```

*If* you need expandable results *and* the input should broadly be 'text', you could use `\text_expand:n`

```latex
\tl_if_blank:eTF { \text_expand:n { \@date } }
  { TRUE CODE }
  { FALSE CODE }
```

This will work as `\text_expand:n` works carefully to be close-to `\protected@edef` but by expansion - but it really is intended for 'text like' material.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! Please allow me ask one more question: could you please demonstrate how to make you first approach concerning "typeset output" into a new command, say `\tl_if_output_blank:NTF` or `\tl_if_output_blank:nTF`? I've never learned how to define such a command for bool testing and am curious in the way to do so.

Comment: @Jinwen I can, but I'll keep it private: one could run into a case where the content has no width but it not blank (think `\hss` or similar)